# add fragment to fragment working well,but finish() method to remove second fragment not working well

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am adding a fragment into a `RelativeLayout` which is a small part of other fragment(containing viewpager) which is adding well, but when i am trying to vanish the fragment calling `finish()` its not working.

xml code:

```
</RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Share you thoughts here..."
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_status_background"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/editTextWritePostId"
                />



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="#f9f9f9"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutIdNewsFeedForPostBar"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Post"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="#1470a6"
                    android:id="@+id/postButtonId"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/checkInButtonId"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/smileyButtonId"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_checkin"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/smiley"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageUploadButtonId"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/smileyButtonId"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/camera"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/videoUploadButtonId"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageUploadButtonId"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

               **//adding new fragment to below layout**
                **<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutIdForSmiley"
                    >
                </RelativeLayout>**

        </LinearLayout>
```

Fragment code to remove new fragment:

```
smileyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                SmileyShowFragment smileyFragment=new SmileyShowFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if(!(smileyFragment.isVisible())) {
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayoutIdForSmiley, smileyFragment, "Smiley").commit();
                }else {
                    relativeLayoutIdForSmiley.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

I am trying to vanish the RelativeLayout with visibility gone and also vanish fragment with `getActivity().finish()` but none of these working.can you help me please. I have searched internet a lot which are same as i am doing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I have figured out your issue. Here is what you are doing the mistake. In your smileButton onclick you are creating a new instance of SmileyShowFragment(`SmileyShowFragment smileyFragment=new SmileyShowFragment();`) and checking weather the fragment is visible using `if(!smileyFragment.isVisible())`. No matter how many time you trigger your click, this condition will be true always, as the fragment instance is created every time you the click the button. The solution is, create the instance of the fragment outside of the button click. Try some thing like this.

```
final SmileyShowFragment smileyFragment = new SmileyShowFragment();
smileyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.relativeLayoutIdForSmiley);
            if(!(fragment instanceof SmileyShowFragment)) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayoutIdForSmiley, smileyFragment, "Smiley").commit();
            }else {
                fragmentTransaction.remove(smileyFragment).commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: my mistake, its working but not fragment not recreating on button click

Comment: thank you its working really well.can you help me on more issue please.

Comment: i was showing some server data in the fragment but its not showing while recreating

Comment: @AAA Post your query. I will help if I could.

Comment: actually the fragment i was loading and removing it contains viewpager with some fragments and and each fragment showing data from server. while first time fragment loading its showing with server data but after removing and recreating fragment its not showing server data

Comment: khumar, the fragment i am adding and removing, showing some image from server.is it possible to show the image without downloading from server while recreate the fragment?

Comment: Use Image loading libraries like Picasso, Glide and Fresco.

Comment: i have solved the issue meanwhile :). thank you for your cordial help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to use `detach` or `remove` on your fragment ?

Go check : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: yes i did, but as i added the fragment to another thats why all fragment gone with that. BTW if you can specify more please